# Get checked:check boxes and put them in a array (depending on closest UL)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to build an webpage what is posting filters trough an Ajax-call to PHP and manipulate the data to display.

This is the code I use for getting the values/data.

```
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");    

$checkboxes.on("change", function()
{
    var opts = getFilterOptions();          
 });


function getFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];                   
    $checkboxes.each(function()
    {
    if(this.checked)
    {                               
        opts.push(this.id);
    }
    });
    return opts;
}
```

I have a hard time with the checkboxes (I use jQuery btw). I would like to get the id of the checked items in combination with the closest 'ul'. 
I tried to use

```
opts.push(this.closest('ul').id, this.id);
```

But then i get duplicate array-names. E.g:

```
[0 => 'category: item1']
[1 => 'category: item2']
[2 => 'category: item3']
[3 => 'othercategory: value1']
[4 => 'othercategory: value2']
```

I also tried a (not so dynamic but hardcoded solution:)

```
function getFilterOptions()
{
 var opts = [];

 var activity = $('input:checkbox:checked.activity').map(function () 
 {
     return this.id;
 }).get();
 console.log(activity);
 return activity;

 var othercategory = $('input:checkbox:checked.othercategory').map(function () 
 {
    return this.id;
 }).get();
 console.log(othercategory);
     return othercategory;
}
```

But this only logs the first checkboxes and not the second (othercategory).

I would like to select all category's in the 'ul'. For example:

```
['category (ul)']
    [0 => 'item1', 1 => 'item2']
['othercategory (a other ul)']
    [0 => 'value1', 1 => 'value2']
```

[What I try to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQzfb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing jQuery and DOM methods. `closest()` is a jQuery method, so you need to call it on `$(this)`, not `this`. `id` is a DOM property, you can't call it on a jQuery object. So it should be:

```
opts.push($(this).closest("ul").attr("id"), this.id);
```

But it looks like you shouldn't be using an array, you need an object whose keys are the categories.

```
var opts = {};
$checkboxes.filter(":checked").each(function() {
    var cat = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
    if (!opts[cat]) {
        opts[cat] = [];
    }
    opts[cat].push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Bermar, thanks for your reply! I tried to use this method but the result of category is a string in stead of a key. (so 'activity' or 'category' is seen by php as a string).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Javascript arrays don't have keys, they just have numbered elements.